How do I store a hexadecimal representation of a file and then output it to create a copy of said file? C++
I'm relatively new to programming and I'm trying to write an application that outputs the hexadecimal representation of a file into a text file, then writes the bytes into a vector of unisgned chars and basically creates a copy of the original file. The problem I'm running into is that the application ends up outputting an empty file. Otherwise, the code appears to work fine; the text file contains the hexadecimal representation of the bytes and the bytes are correctly written into the byte vector. I apologize for the crappy code in advance.
EDIT: I have found out two things: 1. the file is only output empty when the original exceeds a certain size, 2. even when it is output and the size is nearly the same, there is still a number of bytes that are missing - causing the file to become corrupted and unopenable.
int main()
{
    ifstream ifile;
    ofstream ofile;
    ofstream ofile2;
    ifstream ifile2;
    string filename;
    unsigned char byte;
    unsigned int hexnum = 0;
    vector <unsigned char>charvec;

    cout << "input file name" << endl << endl;
    cin >> filename;

    ifile.open(filename, ios::binary);
    ofile.open("OUT" + filename + ".txt");

    if (ifile)
    {
        while (ifile >> byte)
        {
            ofile << "0x" << hex << static_cast<int>(byte) << ' ';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "file not open";
    }

    ifile.close();
    ofile.close();

    ifile2.open("OUT" + filename + ".txt");
    ofile2.open("OUT" + filename, ios::binary | ios::out);

    if (ifile2)
    {
        while (ifile2 >> hex >> hexnum)
        {
            charvec.push_back(hexnum);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "file not open";
    }
   
    // checking the contents of the byte vector    
    for (char i : charvec)
    {
        cout << i << ' ';
    }
    
    copy(charvec.cbegin(), charvec.cend(), ostream_iterator<unsigned char>(ofile2));
   
    Sleep(10000000);
}


You mean like this : std::string s = std::format("0x{:x}", 42); // s == 0x2a. And the other way around you use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol with base 16

Possibly related to the question, I use xxd utility to convert files to hex, and the hex back to files.

Don't use formatted I/O for binary data.

What's the point of Sleep(10000000) call? This sleeps for some 3 hours. My guess is, you are looking at the output file while the program is still in this Sleep; or, you are killing it before it finishes sleeping. In either case, ofile2 is not closed or flushed - that's likely why it appears empty.

What if you output to the console (std::cout) instead? Is the output as expected? If so, all the output processing is not your problem, it's just how you handle the output file. Work on that in a separate test program to analyse the situation. Apply the fix to your program afterwards. See also [mcve] for further context on that approach. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

How about something like this?
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

void
Hex_Dump(uint8_t const *    p_array,
         unsigned int       length,
         std::ostream&      dump_stream)
{
    std::string     char_representation;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        const unsigned int      i_mod_16(i % 16);
        if (i_mod_16 == 0u)
        {
            dump_stream << std::setw(4) << std::dec << std::setfill('0') << i << "    ";
            char_representation.clear();
        }

        dump_stream << " "
                    << std::setw(2) << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<unsigned int>(p_array[i]);
        const char c = static_cast<char>(p_array[i]);
        if (std::isprint(c))
        {
            char_representation += c;
        }
        else
        {
            char_representation += '.';
        }

        if (i_mod_16 == 7u)
        {
            dump_stream << "  ";
            char_representation += ' ';
        }

        if (i_mod_16 == 15)
        {
            dump_stream << "    " << char_representation << "\n";
        }
    }   
}

You may want to get the source to *nix "octal dump" or "od".
